# How to get the iOS Version with Google Analytics

Tags: ios, google-analytics

How can I get the iOS-Version of the mobile visitors of a webpage with Google Analytics?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the "browser" results, and then filter Safari by version, you can infer the version of iOS.

eg:

- Safari 7534.48.3 is iOS 5
- Safari 6533.18.5 is iOS 4
- etc

I still haven't found a definitive list mapping Safari versions to iOS versions (esp. wrt minor iOS verions) but I'm sure it's out there somewhere.

Answer (score 15):

### Current answer

1. In your Reports section, go to "Tech" -> "Tech details".

   [image: screenshot]
2. In the table below the graph, select "OS with version" using the dropdown.

   [image: screenshot]
3. Using the "Add filter" button, add a filter "Operating system exactly matches iOS" and click "Apply".

   [image: screenshot]

Here's what it looks like:

[image: screenshot]

---

### Historical answer

For old analytics properties (before Google Analytics 4):

1. In the sidebar, select "Audience -> Mobile -> Devices".
2. Switch the "Primary Dimension" to "Operating System".
3. Click through to iOS.

[image: Where to click]

Result:

[image: What you see]

---

Bonus tip: To get subtotals by major version, like "all iOS 8", use the search function to search for `^8` (a regex meaning "starts with 8"):

[image: Using the search function]

Answer (score 13):

Click on `Audience > Devices and Networks` then on `view full report` below the `Mobile Device Branding` table. Now choose `Operating System Version` as secondary dimension.

This gives you a list grouped by session, but you can also choose to group it by user (see below), when you add it to your dashboard and edit it there.

[image: iOS Operating System Version]

Comment: How I can see detail of Others?

Answer (score 4):

I know a question is old, but for those who still trying to find it in 2022 with new GA UI here's correct solution:

1. Reports->Tech->Tech details, there press pencil icon in the up right corner (Customize report)

[image: customize reports]

2. Click Browser, see drop-down menu, from there select OS Version

[image: browser]

3. Voila,

> охапка дров репорт готов

Answer (score 1):

I think one way would be to create a custom "user defined" filter for Analytics.

[This post](http://analytics.blogspot.com/2009/07/segment-your-traffic-with-user-defined.html) should lead you in the right direction.

You can access the iOS version in the user agent, which you can find via javascript, and then maybe create a new "user defined" filter for each os versions ?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to get OS version without specifying anything special at the front end side. Choose the following from Google Analytics portal

`Choose App Overview  -> Screens (View full report)  -> Choose Secondary Dimension as Operating System Version`

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested only in IOS version (and not other mobile OS) you should use 
the "Grouped By: Operating System Version".
This grouping option will give you the version number (6.1,5.3,4.1.3 and more)

If you have other OS users you should use the "Operation System" option to filter the data.